# Code to autoland DJI matrice 100

Tags: controls, dji-sdk

I am working on developing program for autonomous control of DJI matrice drone. I like to have precise landing of DJI drone with tolerance of approx 5cm in X and Y axes. For this I am trying to control the drone until 50cm from ground and then immediately landing() function is called. But after the landing() function is called, I see that the drone moves in X and Y directions as well. Due to this landing within defined tolerance fails. Is there a way, that I may write an own code for autolanding program with different constraints.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of a few tools:

1. Use flightCtrl APIs such as `positionAndYawControl` documented [here](http://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/classDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1Control.html) to command the drone in the z-axis, slowly reducing the z position desired
2. Monitor flight status using `broadcast->getStatus()` as documented [here](http://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/classDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1DataBroadcast.html#aa183fef7e062139a32d361b3788d3c7f), and keep sending lower z-setpoints till the drone's flight status changes to `M100FlightStatus::LANDING`
3. Send `disArm()` command to turn the motors off and ensure that the status changes to `M100FlightStatus::FINISHING_LANDING`.

You might have to experiment a little with the z set points and the time duration to keep sending lower setpoints in order to get this to work.